# Taking one digit at a time input input in java

Tags: java

I have a integer input that contains byte values 0 or 1 that are formatted without any whitespace between, like 1010111101010010010101. I want to make a [1, 0, 1, ...] out of those, reading one digit at a time.

Or say i have integer input as 12 and a two variables a and b
i want to assign 1 to a and 2 to b,How can I do that?

Comment: what is the data type of `input`? string? integer?

Comment: input are integer values

Comment: btw, your example pseudo-binary number (1010111101010010010101) is too large for the Java integer range.

Comment: @hoijui OP never said his goal was to parse a Java integer.

Comment: actually he did (in the comments), but you have a point, it can be understood in different ways. @9codie05, please specify the input more precise, as a code example, with the expected output, also in code.

Comment: This question should really be closed as "Unclear". Everyone who looks at it seems to see a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Byte> split(final int number) {

    final List<Byte> output = new LinkedList<Byte>();

    int remainder = number;
    while (remainder > 0) {
        output.add(0, (byte) (remainder % 10));
        remainder = remainder / 10;
    }

    return output;
}

public static void testSplit(final int number) {
    System.err.printf("testSplit(%d): %s\n", number, split(number).toString());
}

public static void testSplits() {

    testSplit(10101001);
    testSplit(12);
}
```

> testSplit(10101001): [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>
> testSplit(12): [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have integer input as 12 and two variables a and b I want to assign 1 to a and 2 to b

Are you try to do this?

```
int input = 1234;
String a = "";
String b = "";
boolean flag = false;
while(input !=0) {
    if (flag) {
        a += Integer.toString(input % 10);
    } else {
        b += Integer.toString(input % 10);
    }
    flag = !flag;
    input /= 10;
}
a = new StringBuffer(a).reverse().toString();
b = new StringBuffer(b).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

The output is:

> 13
>
> 24

[Run live](http://ideone.com/70TE4a).

Note, I used `a` and `b` as *string*, which can easily be converted into *integer*.

Comment: what if input is too large say 500 digits?

Comment: @TusharSaha, OP said the input is an `Integer`.